# What does "premature end of file" mean in GNU makefile?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to practice if statements in makefile, but it keeps saying premature end of file.
Code:

```
test_rule:
   if  [ yes ]
       echo "if works"
   endif
```

Output:

```
make test_rule
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error : premature end of file
make: *** [Makefile:13: test_rule] Error 1
```

I tried using a lot of code online (such as replacing [] by () or adding @ in front of echo) but nothing worked.

Comment: Recipe lines have to start with a tab, but you used 3 spaces.

Comment: Make is one of the few programs where the difference between tabs and spaces really matters.  The creator of `make`, Stu Feldman, has admitted it was a mistake, but by the time that was realized, there were too many users to risk changing it.  See [Tabs and Makefiles](https://beebo.org/haycorn/2015-04-20_tabs-and-makefiles.html) amongst other places.

Comment: This looks useful too: http://gromnitsky.users.sourceforge.net/articles/notes-for-new-make-users/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've noticed it but I don't think that's the problem (copy-pasted the tabs just to make sure)

Comment: It's definitely not related to tabs.  The error message would be completely different: you'd get a make syntax error not a shell syntax error.  Let's reward people like RJ9 who actually provide complete, useful questions including error messages, by reading them carefully and using that information to make sure we give the appropriate answers...!  The problem here is missing backslashes as G.M. points out.

Comment: I hope you're not really using the actual `yes` program in your test :).

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, it was actually the missing backlash. Originally I wasn't using it but I just decided to set ```if``` to ```true```  because I wasn't able to make it work no matter what I tried...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers/comments suggest your 'tabbing' is incorrect -- which may be true -- but looking at the error message...

```
make test_rule
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error : premature end of file
make: *** [Makefile:13: test_rule] Error 1
```

I think it's just a case of incorrect shell syntax in the command.  Keep in mind that, generally speaking, each line in the command section of a make recipe will be run in its own shell.  Try the following (keeping in mind I'm no shell expert)...

```
test_rule:
    if [ yes ]; then \
      echo "it works"; \
    fi
```

Comment: Even better, write it in one line: `if [ yes ]; then echo "it works"; fi` -- easier maintainable. Basic premise is correct of course: Recipees aren't "shell snippets", they are one command per line.

Comment: Or even better, just `[ yes ] && echo "it works"` :)

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I had to finish some other assignments. But thanks a lot, it works! The terminal says that the echo command can't be found but the if works

Answer (score 4):

As [the manual explains](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction), you need to use tabs (by default):

> **Please note:** you need to put a tab character at the beginning of every recipe line! This is an obscurity that catches the unwary. If you prefer to prefix your recipes with a character other than tab, you can set the `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable to an alternate character (see Special Variables).

Therefore, you need to write:

```
foo:
    gcc
```

In other words, that is the string `foo:\n\tgcc\n`.

Note that StackOverflow converts the tab into 4 spaces when rendering the Markdown (but if you try to edit this answer, you will see the tab character).